# How to allow null values on Foreign keys using EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How to allow null values on Foreign keys using EF?

```
public class User
{
    public User() 
    { 
    }

    public int idUser; { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual Computer Computer{ get; set; }
}

public class Computer
{
    public Computer() 
    {
    }
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int idUser{ get; set; }
    public string ComputerName {get;set;}
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Running this I'm getting `not null` on the foreign key.

Comment: Use the `?` keyword. Like: `public virtual Computer? Computer { get; set;}`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> How to allow null values on Foreign keys using EF?

Your database table should allow nulls as well if you are planning to take the following approach:

change

```
public int idUser; { get; set; }
[Required]
public string UserName { get; set; }
public virtual Computer Computer { get; set; }
```

To

```
public int idUser; { get; set; }
[Required]
public string UserName { get; set; }
public virtual Computer Computer{ get; set; }
```

And change

```
[Key, ForeignKey("User")] 
public int idUser { get; set; }
public string ComputerName { get; set; }
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

To

```
[Key, ForeignKey("User")] 
public int? idUser { get; set; }
public string ComputerName { get; set; }
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

The `?`  character, makes a field [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Make sure it is nullable in your database as well.

Comment: what about string datatype?

Comment: @Luciekulza A string is a reference type and `nullable` by default.

Comment: Need I to write the `?` character on `User?` and `int?` the same time?

Comment: Only for User and Computer, since those are the foreign keys you want to be nullable

Comment: What the @#!@#$? the ? character is to allow nullable types for basic data (int, double, bool, etc). A Class by definition is already a nullable type. This answer makes no sense.

Comment: @Keith Database should be equal to code, if he decides to make this foreign key nullable at the database, same should be done in code for cosistency.

Comment: That's true, but your answer is still incorrect. you CANNOT use ? on an already nullable type. The ? MUST be on the int? idUser property. If you don't believe me, try your solution. It will NOT compile.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong.  As per @Keith comment, unless `User` is a `struct` then the code won't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using code first. If that is the case then you override OnModelCreating in the context class and add the following line

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Computer>().HasOptional(c => c.User);
```

================
Ok, you changed your post after I posted my answer.

You can use

int? idUser

for your user ID, this will let EF know that you are allowing a nullable relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `?` keyword. It makes your type a `Nullable` type.

For example `int` doesn't allow nulls normally.

But after appending a `?` to `int` you can assign null to it.

```
int? iCanHaveNull = null;
```

Comment: only for int, but what about string or guid

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, I know, but it is an important topic.

You are trying to setup navigation properties. If you declare it correctly (as shown in the example below), then:

- The property `Computer` contained in the `User` class is referring to ("points to") a computer by using foreign key `idComputer`.
- Likewise, the property `User` contained in the `Computer` class is referring to ("points to") a User by using a foreign key `idUser`.

EF introduces this foreign key automatically if

- You decorate the primary key `Id` of each entity with a `[Key]` attribute. A primary key **must not be nullable** per definition.
- You declare the navigation property correctly (e.g. `public virtual Computer Computer { get; set; }` - which creates by convention a foreign key explicitly named via the ForeignKey attribute as `idComputer`). This foreign key is per definition nullable, unless you add the `[Required]` attribute to the navigation property. 
   For example, if you want to make the foreign key in the `User` entity referring to ("pointing to") `Computer` mandatory, the declaration `[Key, ForeignKey("idComputer"), Required]` would do that.

**Special Note for EF Core:** You have to create a migration in the package manager console via

> `dotnet ef migrations add CreateMyDatabase`

And then apply it to the database via:

> `dotnet ef database update --context myDbContext --project myProject`

(replace CreateMyDatabase, myDbContext and myProjects by names of your choice - but myDbContext and myProjects must exist in your solution).

This is using toolset 5.0.3, you might need to upgrade it via 
`dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.3`

**Example:**

```
// using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
// using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class User
{

    public User() {}

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    
    [Key, ForeignKey("idComputer")]
    public virtual Computer Computer { get; set; }
}

public class Computer
{
    public Computer() {}

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ComputerName { get; set; }
    
    [Key, ForeignKey("idUser")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

It might look weird to have something like `public virtual User User { get; set}` but this is a convention telling EF it is a navigation property, and all that is created in the database table is a foreign key (here: `idUser` in table `Computer`).
You can find a good description with some additional information here:

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/ef-core-relationships-navigation-properties/